# Custom UIScrollView Gesture

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, gestures

I have a `collection view cell` which contains an `UIScrollview` in which all of the content sits. I want to have a gesture that allows users to **swipe down** when the cell is at 0,0 and then that fades away into the list view of the collection view.

However, I still want the users to be able to **scroll down** into the rest of the cell content.

Should this be contained in the same gesture? If so, how do I override a scrollview's gesture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea just try implement this method from `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Get scrollView and calculate gestures and make behaviour. And look other methods for make best visual effect :)

Comment: How do I get stuff like translations and whether or not the user is scroll up or down from this? @Bimawa

Comment: scrollView have a property `contentOffset` try use it.